# How filter on date (between two dates) with two columns in my dataframe in pyspark

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I want to filter my `df` between two date columns, example :

```
+------+----------+----------+
|  code|     Date1|     Date2|
+------+----------+----------+
|    10|2018-06-01|2018-06-05|
|    15|2018-06-01|2018-06-15|
|    16|2018-06-01|2018-06-20|
|+------+----------+---------+
```

when I try this :

```
test_df = df.select('code','revenue').where(F.col('Date1').between('Date1','Date2'))
```

I have an empty result.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be -

```
test_df = df.select('code','revenue').where(F.col('Date1').between(F.col('Date1'),F.col('Date2')))
```

Otherwise, it treats 'Date1' as a value (i.e constant across all rows) and won't compare it to the column value. BTW - this will always be true.